# Get missing objects from 2 arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let selected = [
  {id: 15, name: 'Canada'},
  {id: 25, name: 'Germany'}
];

let all = [
  {id: 15, name: 'Canada'},
  {id: 25, name: 'Germany'},
  {id: 32, name: 'United States'},
  {id: 40, name: 'China'}
]
```

How do I get non-selected countries from `all` objects and print it out in another variable? Based on `id` key of those which are in `selected` array?

Comment: Caveat, remember that `{id: 25, name: 'Germany'} !== {id: 25, name: 'Germany'}`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to find all objects that aren't contained in `selected` and then do something with them:

```
let nonSelectedItems = all.filter(obj => selected.every(s => s.id !== obj.id));

//do stuff with non-selected items
```

Comment: oops I forgot to say that it's React's object. `typeof` returns object :(

Comment: @knitevision: What do you mean by "React's object"? What does that have to do with the problem?

Comment: @FelixKling Array.prototype.filter does not work on objects :(

Comment: @knitevision: So you are saying, `all` is not an array like in your example? Why did you make the question about arrays then? We cannot help you if you are asking about something different than you have. Please update your question and provide a better example. Btw, `typeof` returns `"object"` for arrays because arrays are objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` and `find`, so as soon as element with same `id` is found in `selected` it will filter out that element from `all`. You can also use `some` instead of `find`.

```js
let selected = [
  {id: 15, name: 'Canada'},
  {id: 25, name: 'Germany'}
];

let all = [
  {id: 15, name: 'Canada'},
  {id: 25, name: 'Germany'},
  {id: 32, name: 'United States'},
  {id: 40, name: 'China'}
]

var r = all.filter(e => !selected.find(a => e.id === a.id));
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate an object which holds id as a property using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method(which helps to speed up since you need to iterate over and over) and use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) method to filter elements from `all` array.

```
// generate the object reference
let ref = selected.reduce(function(obj, o) {
  // define property
  obj[o.id] = true;
  // return object property
  return obj;
  // set initial value as an object
}, {});

// filter out array elements
let res = all.filter(function(o) {
  return !ref[o.id]
})
```

```js
let selected = [{
  id: 15,
  name: 'Canada'
}, {
  id: 25,
  name: 'Germany'
}];

let all = [{
  id: 15,
  name: 'Canada'
}, {
  id: 25,
  name: 'Germany'
}, {
  id: 32,
  name: 'United States'
}, {
  id: 40,
  name: 'China'
}]

let ref = selected.reduce(function(obj, o) {
  obj[o.id] = true;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(
  all.filter(function(o) {
    return !ref[o.id]
  })
)
```

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

```
let ref = selected.reduce((obj, o) => (obj[o.id] = true, obj), {});

let res = all.filter(o => !ref[o.id]);
```

```js
let selected = [{
  id: 15,
  name: 'Canada'
}, {
  id: 25,
  name: 'Germany'
}];

let all = [{
  id: 15,
  name: 'Canada'
}, {
  id: 25,
  name: 'Germany'
}, {
  id: 32,
  name: 'United States'
}, {
  id: 40,
  name: 'China'
}]

let ref = selected.reduce((obj, o) => (obj[o.id] = true, obj), {});

console.log(
  all.filter(o => !ref[o.id])
)
```